# An easier way to match a pattern either x or y times

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to write a regex to validate a numerical code. The code can be one of a few valid lengths, but *not* all of the lengths between. I know I can do something like

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{".$x."}|[0-9]{".$y".})$/", "$string")
```

but would rather not have to repeat the subpattern for each valid length. Especially as my actual regular expression is already going to be on the complex side.

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{".$x.",".$y."})$/", "$string")
```

obviously won't work for me, as it would also match any number of digits between `$x` and `$y`.

Is their an easier way to use a regex to match a pattern either *x* **or** *y* times?

#### Edit:

While my complete regex is a bit complex, the portion that can be repeated x **or** y times is very simple [0-9], so answers like the ones given by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653960/3938807) and [barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654099/3938807), while interesting, will not solve the problem in this particular case.

Comment: Just alternation as you have, you can't group range operators to repeat the preceding token because the preceding token wouldn't be quantifiable. For instance, `^\d(?:{3}|{10})$` will not work.

Comment: @hwnd I was afraid of that. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Well, not just alternations of duplicate expressions. There is always function calls. ie; a named sub-pattern, available in php (PCRE). This is also a functional way to factor expressions.

Answer (score 1):

> Especially as my actual regular expression is already going to be on the complex side.

Then this is the only alternative available in all of Regular Expression land.

I guess since this is PHP, you can always put a singular unit in a function, then call the function using a range quantifier in a series of alternations...

You can rename the function's a little less descriptive, like A, B, or C ...
The big advantage is that you can inject other separator code, for instance
`(?:(?&digit)\s*){4}` or whatever you want.

```
 # \b(?:(?&digit){4}|(?&digit){7}|(?&digit){9}|(?&digit){11})\b(?(DEFINE)(?<digit>[0-9]))

 \b                    # add a boundary here
 (?:
      (?&digit){4}          # match 4 times
   |  (?&digit){7}          # or, match 7 times
   |  (?&digit){9}          # or, match 9 times
   |  (?&digit){11}         # or, match 11 times
 )
 \b                    # add a boundary here

 (?(DEFINE)            # Add complex expressions here
      (?<digit> [0-9] )     # (1)
 )
```

Input:  `1234 1234567 123456789`

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
1234  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 5 , len 7 ) 
1234567  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 13 , len 9 ) 
123456789
```

Comment: A backreference doesn't repeat the previous pattern, it matches the actual string that was matched previously.

Answer (score 0):

Put the complex pattern in a variable, then use that in the regexp.

```
$pat = 'complex pattern';
preg_match("/^($pat{" . $x . "}|$pat{" . $y . "})$/", $string);
```

Note, by the way, that I had to use concatenation rather than substitution to get `$x` and `$y` inside the `{}` in the regexp. This is because `{$var}` is the syntax for "complex variable substitution" in PHP strings, so the `{}` will not appear in the resulting string. See the PHP documentation on [double quoted strings](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: That was absentminded of me. I have edited my post to correct my error.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid manually writing your subpattern multiple times by leveraging a subpattern reference (`(?1)`).  Order your quantifier logic ascending, then perform subtraction on the two variables to calculate the secondary/optional extension.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/E22Bk))

```
$tests = [
    '333666',
    '333',
    '333666999',
];

$x = 6;
$y = 9;
var_export(
    preg_grep(
        "/^(\d){{$x}}(?:(?1){" . ($y - $x) . "})?$/",
        $tests
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '333666',
  2 => '333666999',
)
```

Without seeing your "complex pattern", I cannot determine if my advice is a practical/readable solution.